# ui-grid disappears on select click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui-grid

I have a problem with the dropdown in ui-grid.

This is my cell template where it must be.

```
{
            cellTemplate: '<div>{{ row.entity.deviceType }}</div>',
            displayName: $filter('prefixTranslate')('device_type', 'devices'),
            field: 'deviceType',
            key: 'deviceType',
            name: 'column_device_type',
            height: 40,
            enableCellEdit: true,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
            editType: 'dropdown',
            editableCellTemplate: `
                <div>
                  <form
                    name="inputForm">
                    <select
                      class="my-select"
                      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
                      ui-grid-edit-dropdown
                      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"
                      ng-options="field[editDropdownIdLabel] as field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray">
                    </select>
                  </form>
                </div>
            `,
            editDropdownValueLabel: 'deviceType',
            editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                { id: 1, deviceType: 'Vertical Tank' },
                { id: 2, deviceType: 'Horizontal Tank' }
            ]
        },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57YLI.jpg)

When you dblclick on the cell, the select (1) element appears, then you click on select element and it disappears. This problem can be solved only by fast mouseover on the popup (2)

So when I click on select element it just disappears and the default cell is shown... I don't know why it happens

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please make a plunker for this issue

Comment: @Adjit, sorry, I just edited my question. Thank you